# How does the browser determine the order in which conflicting (overlapping) intervals run?

Tags: javascript

```
setInterval(function () {
    console.log("10 ==>" + new Date()); // -- > 1st
}, 1000);

setInterval(function () {
    console.log("10000 ==>" + new Date()); // -- 2nd
}, 10000);
```

Little confused with above code.

Can both (1st and 2nd) execute when cycle 10000 completes (No..is should not. Javascript is single threaded. But then who gets chance)

Also when I went through [how timer works](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/#postcomment),

> Note that while mouse click handler is executing the first interval
>   callback executes. As with the timer its handler is queued for later
>   execution. However, note that when the interval is fired again (when
>   the timer handler is executing) this time that handler execution is
>   dropped. If you were to queue up all interval callbacks when a large
>   block of code is executing the result would be a bunch of intervals
>   executing with no delay between them, upon completion. Instead
>   browsers tend to simply wait until no more interval handlers are
>   queued (for the interval in question) before queuing more.

**Note that while mouse click handler is executing the first interval
callback executes.**

This line is confusing. Does this means when click handler was executes the first interval callback also gets a chance to execute?

Comment: Wait....wait...what is unclear.?

Comment: Great question. Upvoted. I was a little confused at first, but it's asking for clarification on this paragraph, extracted from John Resig's article on how JS timers work internally. http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: In your `setInterval` example, the two `setInterval` calls have different timeout values. Is that correct? If so, the first one will execute, then later the second one will execute. Apologies, but I'm not sure why that would be confusing.

Comment: Yes, someone please re-open this question. I've read John Resig's article twice over, and I'm struggling to put his explanation into plainer English. Perhaps someone else can?

Comment: Thanks...i hope someone will reopen this

Comment: @Sam in theory, they overlap at t+10000ms

Comment: @royhowie thanks for making title clear..can you help me understand timers

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I kept thinking of `setTimeout` while reading it!

Comment: @royhowie what happens when they overlap then?

Comment: From my understanding, `setInterval(fn, TIME)` will attempt to queue its callback, `fn`, every `TIME` ms, regardless of whether the last interval has completed. This does not mean the execution of `fn` will begin immediately, however, since JavaScript is single-threaded + async and the event queue may or may not be open. For example, say you have `setInterval(fn, 10)`. At t=0, the interval starts. However, you also begin executing `someReallyComputationallyIntensiveFn` at t=0. This function takes 20ms to complete; it blocks the event queue. `setInterval` will not fire until after it completes.

Comment: Yep that's pretty much it. John Resig replies in the comments to his article with some words to that effect too, here http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/#comment-298066

Comment: what in case of `setInterval(fn, 10)` and `setInterval(fn, 10)` started at at t=0 . which will be executed first?

Comment: One of them will be called slightly before the other. My example above oversimplified the problem. One of the interval or `someReallyComput…` will be called at t=0ms and the other slightly after (e.g., at t=1ms), since JS only has one thread to work on. If you have two `setInterval(fn, 10)`, one will be called first and will queue its callback first on every iteration.

Comment: what happened even after re-opening question? did you get answer? deleting your question would be go.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I am waiting for experts like you to address and answer

Comment: @royhowie can you post answer so that others will also find it easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are free to implement the callback queue in different ways. You may get different results depending on how the browser is implemented. In cases like this, the result is usually random.